# Ext.data.JsonStore with special characters

Tags: json, extjs4, special-characters

I am creating a Ext.data.JsonStore for dispalying a chart. The data store it built in C# code behing and inserted into the page via:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Data", dataScript, true);
```

This is the resulting javascript code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
   fields: ["name", "ASAP", "Phase 2", "test", "Version 2.0 SR 1"],

   data: [
{ "name": "ASAP", "ASAP": 30, "Phase 2": 10, "test": 5, "Version 2.0 SR 1": 10 } ,
{ "name": "Phase 2", "ASAP": 12, "Phase 2": 5,  "test": 15, "Version 2.0 SR 1": 5 }   
   ]
});
```

The problem is that in the field "Version 2.0 SR 1" there is a '.' that is causing an a script error.

The error that it returns is:

```
SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' 
ext-all.js, line 18 character 5081
```

I am assuming that I need to encode in some manner, but I have tried modifying the field to with no avail:

```
Version 2\\.0 SR 1
Version 2\.0 SR 1
Version 2\u002E0 SR 1
```

If I remove the '.' or replace it with '_' the code works.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? 4.0.7? 4.1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ext.data.JsonStore class automatically configures itself with a proxy/reader configuration like this:

```
proxy: {
    type  : 'ajax',
    reader: 'json',
    writer: 'json'
}
```

However, this isn't sufficient for the case you've described, since you need to enable the [useSimpleAccessors config](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-useSimpleAccessors) on the JSON reader. The solution, then, is to use a regular Ext.data.Store instead, and specify the proxy and reader explicitly:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            useSimpleAccessors: true
        }
    },

    fields: ["name", "ASAP", "Phase 2", "test", "Version 2.0 SR 1"],

    data: [
        { "name": "ASAP", "ASAP": 30, "Phase 2": 10, "test": 5, "Version 2.0 SR 1": 10 } ,
        { "name": "Phase 2", "ASAP": 12, "Phase 2": 5,  "test": 15, "Version 2.0 SR 1": 5 }   
    ]
});
```